# Margem de um Document iTextPdf

Tags: java, android, itext

Estou trabalhando com um arquivo PDF já existente, segue a pequena linha de código:

```
    //Código...

    document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    // Load existing PDF
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(arquivo);
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    document.setPageSize(reader.getPageSize(1));

    //Código...
```

O meu problema é o seguinte, estou usando o elemento `Paragraph` do `iTextPdf` e alinhando cada `String` no seu devido lugar no arquivo PDF existente usando esses métodos:

```
    paragraph.setIndentationLeft(94f); //Movimenta horizontal
    paragraph.setLeading(14f); //Movimenta vertical
```

Porém, ao colocar uma `String` mais para esguerda ou direita é como se existisse uma margem, um espaço de aproximadamente uma polegada que não consigo ultrapassar, a `String` quebra e continua abaixo dela ou na mesma linha, suspeito que seja alguma configuração do elemento `Document`, usei os seguintes metodos sem sucesso:

```
    document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    document.setMarginMirroring(true);
```

Alguém saberia como posso ZERAR essa margem??? Quero adicionar uma `String` bem na "beirada" do arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Document.setMargins()` só atua na página seguinte. Para atuar na primeira página é necessário chamá-lo antes do open.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo! Não tinha me ligado desse detalhe, estou muito agradecido pois funcionou perfeitamente!